# BufferedReader.reader.readLine() returns nothing in Java

Tags: java, process, bufferedreader, readline, stringbuilder

I have the following code:

```
  Process pr = run.exec(sonarScannerCommand);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader eReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getErrorStream()));

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    boolean error = false;
    
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        output.append(line + "\n");
        if (line.contains("EXECUTION FAILURE")) {
            error = true;
        }
        log.info(line);
    }

    String errorString = "";
    while ((line = eReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (errorString.equals("") && error) {
            errorString = line;
        }
        output.append(line + "\n");
        log.error(line);
    }

    pr.waitFor(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

At some point in the process, it freezes and doesn't move forward.
It returns nothing to the readLine () method and gets stuck waiting for something that doesn't return.
How can I manage this wait?
Thank you

Comment: I think the std_out could block if the err_out is full and not being read.  I think you have to check both in one read loop and read from both if input is available.

Answer (score 0):

You must consume stdout and stderr on different threads, because if one of these output streams fills its buffer while you are only reading from the other stream, then the process blocks indefinitely.

Alternatively switch to using `ProcessBuilder` and map stderr to stdout, then you just read from the merged stream not both streams:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process pr = pb.start();
... Your reading code for reader, eReader is not required
int rc = exec.waitFor();
```